# Angular filter date: The difference between passing on the local timezone parameter and not passing the timezone parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, angular-filters

The difference between passing on the local timezone parameter and not passing the filter timezone parameter in the angularjs.
This is my code:

```
var timezoneLocal = new Date().getTimezoneOffset().toString(); // "-480"
var dateUCT = "2018-09-22T11:19:08Z";
var formatDate = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm";
var formatWithTimeZone = $filter('date')(dateUCT, formatDate, timezoneLocal); // "22/09/2018 05:59"
var formatWithoutTimezone = $filter('date')(dateUCT, formatDate); // "22/09/2018 07:19"
```

As far as I know, if you do not pass the timezone, then the default is timezone local. But why when I go live, the result is different when I do not transmit?

Why are there differences?

Answer (score 0):

[From the AngularJS docs for date filter:](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

> Timezone to be used for formatting. It understands UTC/GMT and the continental US time zone abbreviations, but for general use, use a time zone offset, for example, '+0430' (4 hours, 30 minutes east of the Greenwich meridian) If not specified, the timezone of the browser will be used.

So it is an optional argument that renders the date in a specific timezone if provided.